# Multiple joins in the same table

Tags: sql, postgresql

Example of my DB:

```
ID     APP     USER_ID    SESSION_ID  LOCAL_TIME  CONTEXT  ACTION       VALUE
141    App1    userID1     session1   2019-07-18   Player   Name      PlayerName1
141    App1    userID1     session1   2019-07-18   Player    XP          486
141    App1    userID1     session2   2019-07-18   App     BuildNum     11184
452    App1    userID4     session1   2019-07-18   Player   Name      PlayerName2
```

I have a query I run in my ti_userevent database that combines a users play session lengths from multiple play sessions into one play session length. It returns it as a total play length for each user who played between a set time and date (Instead of 4 sessions for Player 1, it returns 1 and gives me the total play length of all 4 sessions).

This query allows me to set the date and time range for the data I am looking for in MetaBase, and returns the player ID, player name and total play length across multiple sessions for each user within the timeframe provided.

This is the query.

```
SELECT t2.playername,
       (EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM
                 (MAX(t.local_time) - MIN(t.local_time))::INTERVAL)/60)::integer
          as duration
FROM ti_userevent t
   JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT
                t2.value as playerName,
                t2.session_id
         FROM ti_userevent t2
         WHERE context = 'Player' 
           AND action = 'Name'
           [[AND local_time >= {{StartTime}}::timestamp at time zone 'US/Pacific']]
           [[AND local_time < {{EndTime}}::timestamp at time zone 'US/Pacific']]
        ) t2 ON t2.session_id = t.session_id
GROUP BY t2.playername;
```

Example Data:

```
       User ID        User Name   Play Length of all sessions
        ID1             Name 1          105
        ID2             Name 2          215
        ID3             Name 3          352
```

But, what I would like to do is add another variable to the query AND get their lifetime XP from the Query. The problem is, this info is all stored in the same Entity / Attribute value!

To get the lifetime XP, I would have to add the following

```
FROM ti_userevent
WHERE
context = 'Player'
AND action = 'XP'
```

And the other Variable I would like to add (Build Number) is also in the same table and EAV value... To get the build number I would run

```
SELECT DISTINCT session_id
            FROM 
                ti_userevent
            WHERE 
                action = 'BuildNum'
                and value = {{BuildNum}})
```

What I would like is to combine the two EA Values above (XP / Buildnum) to the query at the top... I have tried several times and just suck with joins / EAV databases and variable.

What I am after (With time and BuildNum variables):

```
    User ID          User Name   Play Length of all sessions    Player XP
        ID1             Name 1          105                      1324154
        ID2             Name 2          215                      84415
        ID3             Name 3          352                      4784512
```

Thanks for your time and any help is appreciated!

Comment: An user can have multiple records with `action = 'name'. is it true ? 2. With `action = 'XP' and action = 'BuildNum'` there will be only one record each for an user ? 3. If `Yes` you want a concatenation value of `XP` and `BuildNum` in the final result along with result from first query you have shown ?

Comment: @Sujitmohanty30 I misread your comment the first time, sorry...
There can be multiple records with ```Action = name``` ... However, to get the name you have to do ```Context = 'Player``` and ```Player``` can lead to multiple ```action``` other than ```name```. 2) With ```Action= XP``` and ```Action=BuildNum``` There could still be multiple results for ```XP``` 3) I don't care about returning the ```BuildNum``` value, just want to filter by it... I would prefer one combined ```XP``` value for each user.

Comment: You seem to have decided for a key/value table in your database. These are a nuisance to work with. Is there a good reason why you are not using normalized tables with proper columns instead (e.g. `table session ( start_time timestamp, end_time timestamp, ...) , table session_player ( player_id int, entered_session timestamp, left_session timestamp, avatar_name varchar, ...)`?

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand your data or why you only select 'Name' actions in your query. It seems like the table you are showing is some kind of key/value table, where you store all relevant data belonging to play sessions. It looks like you store there events like "user entered session", "user left session", "user played with name xyz", "user played with build num 1234", etc.

This is only guessing from what I see. So, the following query may still be very different from what you are looking for, but hopefully shows you an approach on how to write your query. This is how to get session data for a user (or so I suppose):

```
select
  user_id, session_id,
  max(local_time)- min(local_time) as duration,
  max(value) filter (where action = 'Name') as name_used,
  max(value) filter (where action = 'XP') as session_xp,
  max(value) filter (where action = 'BuildNum') as session_build
from sessiondata
group by user_id, session_id;
```

Now, if you want the total duration sum of all sessions played by a user, you'd have to aggregate above query result again. But then you'd have to decide, what name to display, what XP etc. Here is one option:

```
select
  user_id,
  sum(duration) as total_playtime,
  string_agg(distinct name_used, ', ') as names_used,
  string_agg(distinct session_xp, ', ') as session_xps,
  string_agg(distinct session_build, ', ') as session_builds
from ( <above query here> ) q
group by user_id
order by user_id;
```